# Oracle Date to_char Returns Different Results

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

I have a database on my local development machine and there is a database on our test server. Basically, the tables on my dev machine were copied over from the test machine.

However, I have found a difference in how the same date is treated by the `to_char` function. On my development machine if I run the following query:

```
select test_date, to_char(test_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
from test.table
where id = 'C0007784'
```

I get the following results:

`31-DEC-99    1999-12-31`

On the test server running the same query against the same schema and data I get the following:

`31-DEC-99    1899-12-31`

Could this difference in behaviour of `to_char` be due to a setting being different in the two Oracle instances?

If I run `SELECT value FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter ='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';` I get `DD-MON-RR` for both instances.

Comment: Are you sure that the underlying data is the same?

Comment: Provided it is the **same data** this is not possible.

Comment: Could you describe precisely how the table was copied from the test machine?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - If selecting from `test_date` (without passing it through any function) returns `31-DEC-99` in both cases, doesn't that mean the underlying data is the same?

Comment: @DavidBrower no it doesn't. The only proper way of year format is 4 digits. Show results with YYYY and we'll see if it is the same.

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski - I used SQL Developer to export the contents of the database on Test to a CSV file and then used it again to import.

Comment: Then perhaps you export stings like `31-DEC-99`. This can be miss-interpreted in target database. Yeats should be **always** four digits. Apparently you did not work in IT world already previous century, otherwise you would be aware of the "year 2000 problem".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you exported the contents of the table to a csv file using DD-MON-YY format. YY obviously causes ambiguity. I guess that when you were importing the file, 99 was interpreted as 1999 instead of 1899. I don't know the exact mechanism which is used by database to guess the full year, but anyway Oracle [strongly recommends YYYY in date format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216):

> Note: Oracle recommends that you use the 4-digit year element (YYYY)
>   instead of the shorter year elements for these reasons: The 4-digit
>   year element eliminates ambiguity.
>
> The shorter year elements may affect query optimization because the
>   year is not known at query compile time and can only be determined at
>   run time.

Comment: When I tried to export the contents of the table as SQL insert statements I see that `1899-12-31` is inserted as `to_date('31-DEC-99','DD-MON-RR')` which becomes `1999-12-31` in my development database. *Whereas* `2012-02-23` is inserted as `to_date('23-FEB-12','DD-MON-RR')` and becomes `2012-02-23` in my development database.